# How to use ResultSetExtractor for JdbcTemplate

Tags: java, sql

I have sql like this

```
truck.selectFullTruckDetail = select * from truck t 
left join orderz o 
on t.truckId = o.truckId  
order by t.truckId
```

which returns a list of trucks and orders that match the trucks like below

```
TRUCKID     TRUCKCODE   PURCHASEDDATE   DESCRIPTION     ORDERID     PETROLQTY   ORDERDATE   TRUCKID
```

I am trying to implement a one to many relationship that should return the table and all informations so did this and have such classes
I am getting **fullTruckDetailsql** is always null , its say my sql statement is always null . what is wrong with my method.

```
List<TruckDetail> getTruckDetails  = namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(fullTruckDetailsql,
        new ResultSetExtractor<List<TruckDetail>>() {

    @Override
    public List<TruckDetail> extractData(ResultSet rs) throws SQLException, DataAccessException {
        Map<Integer, TruckDetail> map = new HashMap<Integer, TruckDetail>();
        TruckDetail truckDetail;
        while (rs.next()) {
            Integer id = rs.getInt("truckId");
            truckDetail = map.get(id);

            if(truckDetail == null){

                String description = rs.getString("descriptions");
                String truckCode =  rs.getString("truckCode");
                Date purchasedDate = rs.getDate("purchasedDate");
                Double avgPerMonth = rs.getDouble("avgPerMonth");

                truckDetail = new TruckDetail(id,truckCode, purchasedDate, description,avgPerMonth);

                map.put(id, truckDetail);
            }

            Order order = new Order(
                    rs.getInt("orderId"),
                    rs.getDouble("qty"),
                    rs.getDate("date"),
                    rs.getInt("id"));

            truckDetail.getOrderList().add(order);

        }
        return new ArrayList<TruckDetail>(map.values());
    }
});
```

And this is the dto class i am trying to map to

```
public class TruckDetail {

    private Integer truckId;

    private String truckCode;
    private Date purchasedDate;
    private String descriptions;
    private List<Order> orderList;
    private Double avgPerMonth;
    }
```

Im not sure my resultsetExtractor is accurate but i also not sure how to continue in order to execute the sql command using either jdbcTemplate or nameParams.. here is what i have done but doesnt work
I am not sure how to continue can any one help please direct me on what is wrong

public final TruckDetail getFullTruckDetail() {

```
    MyObjectExtractor myObjectExtractor = new MyObjectExtractor();
   TruckDetail truckDetails =
            namedParameterJdbcTemplate.query(fullTruckDetail,myObjectExtractor.extractData( )) {
            });

   return truckDetails;
}
```

Comment: What does _but doesn't work_ mean?

Comment: I shall edit , i am not able to complete the method getFullTruckDetail() if you see extract object requires a result set , what could that be ?

Comment: @AndrewS you can check

Comment: Is there an error?  What is the expected result?  What is the actual result?